# Try block inside while loop

Tags: python, try-catch

I am required to get exact 4 integer inputs with delimiter and perform the following operation on it:

```
((num1*num2)+num3)/num4
```

Therefore, I have two errors to deal here. `ValueError` and `ZeroDivisionError.`
My code is as follows:

```
while(True):
    try:
        list1 = list(map(int, input("Enter comma separated values: ").split(",")))
        assert (len(list1)==4)
        result = (((list1[0]*list1[1])+list1[2])/list1[3])
    except ValueError or ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Invalid Input!")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

The program should keep asking for input until valid input is entered.
The program runs properly for two incorrect inputs only i.e. If first time I entered invalid input, it asks for input again as desired. If I again entered invalid input, it simply prints "Invalid Input" but doesn't ask for input again.
Kindly share where might be the problem.

Comment: Try using:- except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you handle multiple exceptions, use a `tuple` of exceptions rather than `or`

```
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
```

If you want to check the type you can do it using `type()`

```
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
    if type(e) is ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
    else:
        print('ZeroDivisionError')
```

Comment: How can I use print statement describing each different error inside the single except block using multiple exceptions. For example here, in this answer, how can I print statement depending upon error is ValueError or ZeroiDivisionError. I tried using If(ValueError) and so on but it didnt work.

Comment: If you want to treat the exceptions differently you should use an own exception block for each exception (as you can see in Sujays answer).

Answer (score 2):

try splitting `ZeroDivisionError` and `ValueError` to 2 separate `except` block. (Because your code would not work for me):

```
try:
    list1 = list(map(int, input("Enter comma separated values: ").split(",")))
    assert (len(list1)==4)
    result = (((list1[0]*list1[1])+list1[2])/list1[3])
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input!")
    continue
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Invalid Input!")
```